# Post Title to link to a PDF

Tags: permalinks, attachments, pdf

I want to link a Post Title to the PDF. I feel my solution is somewhere in `wp_get_attachment_url()` but I can't figure out how. Also, I'd like my pdf to be located in `../wp-content/uploads/year/month/pdf-name.pdf` for about 12 post going back 2 years. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I think this may be of some assistance, hopefully. Good Luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949381/how-can-i-link-wordpress-posts-title-to-pdf-file-download

Comment: The [Page Links To plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/) should take care of that without excess bloat.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) (Very popular plugin).
It lets you create fields and manage their values very easily.

This way you could just create a new field for file upload and then to pull its information like this-

```
<?php
    $my_file = get_field('my_file');
    if( $my_file ) {
        echo $my_file['url'];
        echo $my_file['alt'];
        echo $my_file['...
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from using a plugin to do this. I feel like it should be a pretty simple operation. Just can't believe I'm the first dev to try and do this.